# How to stop ActiveMQ from creating a queue which doesn't exist

Tags: activemq-classic

How to stop ActiveMQ from creating queue which doesn't exist?
I am using ActiveMQ for storing message, but ActiveMQ creates a queue if it doesn't exist. I don't want it to create a queue if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to set up the authorizationPlugin
 http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-restrict-connections-from-creating-new-queues-or-topics.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit destinations creation by configuring the `authorizationPlugin` so that:

- only users with **admins** role can send and read messages and create destinations
- only users with **producers** role can send messages
- only users with **consumers** role can read messages

**add to `activemq.xml`:**

```xml
<plugins>
    <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq"/>

   <authorizationPlugin>
       <map>
         <authorizationMap>
           <authorizationEntries>            
             <authorizationEntry queue="test" read="consumers" write="producers" admin="admins" />
             <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="all" write="all" admin="all"/>
             <authorizationEntry queue="ActiveMQ.>.>" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
           </authorizationEntries>
           <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
             <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
           </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
        </authorizationMap>
      </map>
   </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

**add to `login.config`:**

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties"
        reload=true;
};
```

**add to `users.properties`:**

```
q_consumers=q_consumers_pwd
q_producers=q_producers_pwd
admin=admin
```

**add to `groups.properties`:**

```
admins=admin
consumers=q_consumers
producers=q_producers
all=q_consumers,q_producers,admin
```

**When you create a JMS `Connection` you have to pass user & password:**

```java
javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(String userName, String password);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to answer, but i am not able to find login.config. I can find user.properties

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me!!

Comment: This makes abosulutely no sense for me as I don't have any of these files and wouldn't know a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory from my own buttocks, because I am using a custom C++ client to connect to ActiveMQ and every doc is written in java speak.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz the activemq.xml, users.properties, group.properties and login.config are server-side settings to lock-down authorization for auto-creation. Nothing changes on the client-side, including C++ clients. Once the authorization lock-down is setup, the clients (including C++ clients) will receive a security error when trying to access a queue that does not exist.