# Prohibit create queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: queue, authorization, activemq-classic, message-driven-bean

I have a MessageDrivenBean in my JavaApplication that receives messages from ActiveMQ with destinationpattern 'my.queue.*.consumer'. In my glassfish I have deployed a ActiveMQ-Resource-Adapter (vserion 5.14.1). This adapter connect with user 'glassfishuser' to my ActiveMQ. If I start my application (runs in glassfish) there will be create a queue named 'my.queue.*.consumer' in my ActiveMQ. How can I prevent that this queue will be created?

I tried to configure this in my activemq.xml like this:

```
    <plugins>
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="admin" password="admin" groups="admins"/>
                <authenticationUser username="glassfishuser" password="password" groups="consumers,publishers"/>
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>

        <authorizationPlugin>
          <map>
            <authorizationMap>
              <authorizationEntries>
                <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="consumers, publishers, admins" write="consumers, publishers, admins" admin="consumers, publishers, admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="publishers, admins" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="consumers, admins" write="publishers, admins" admin="admins" />
              </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
          </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: your config seems good, your  queue named 'my.queue.*.consumer' is a temp destination ?

Comment: no, it's not a temp destination

Comment: Have you restarted AMQ broker after authorization settings ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664311/active-mq-how-to-stop-active-mq-from-creating-queue-which-doesnt-exist/43674555#43674555